# I dont ever use Linux or VPS ( Virtual Private Servers ), i can use VPS for my webiste?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, website

i intend to buy http://www.dreamhost.com/hosting-vps.html
for website use apache, php, mysql
and I dont ever use Linux or VPS. I dont sure I can use this. I used Linux shared host once.

Comment: "I've never driven a car, can I go and buy an Audi S4?" -- That's how this reads.

Comment: @Tom - no, you should not. You should get an RS6 Avant, because then it has room for the family and all your stuff when you go on your first ever driving lesson so you can take your whole family out in one foul swoop.

Comment: @Mark I genuinely giggled at this.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to get involved in systems administration then you are better off renting a service where the provider takes care of it, shared web-hosting is one such service. If you need high capacity in terms of CPU or bandwidth, that should be something you can arrange with at least some web-hosting providers. Generally you have little control over the software environment.

If you rent a VPS, you will have to do all the systems administration yourself. However you can install whatever web-server products you want, so if your web-site needs some special software you can just install it.

If you need higher capacity in terms of CPU then VPS probably won't give you that, you'll need a dedicated server. Again you'll need to do all the systems admin but you'll probably also need to ensure the contract covers downtime, replacement of failed hardware, backups and anything else you need.

For really high-capacity you'd rent rack-space and purchase your own hardware to place in it. This has a much higher management and administration overhead for you. You'll need to think carefully about backups, failover, disaster recovery, power, diversity of WAN connections and a hundred other things that really require specialist knowledge. A datacentre can provide much of this but you'll need to know something about it too.

If you are "only a coder" and need a reliable, well-managed service - shared hosting is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you may want to consider hiring a sysadmin, depending on how much/fast you're willing to learn.

Comment: i'll must learn to use Linux if want use VPS ? I only am a coder, it can hard to learn linux and i very need powerful server for website now

Comment: With a VPS, the customer is responsible for maintenance of the virtual server regardless of whether they do it themselves or if they find someone else to do it for them.

Comment: Then perhaps you shouldnt rent a VPS. Perhaps shared hosting is more suited to you?

Comment: There has shared hosting more powerful , can you  introduce to me

Comment: It's very useful to add a string to your bow.  As a programmer, if you understand a little of what is going on server side, it can only improve your programming.  And if you are web developing for Apache, and don't know Apache, then you may find yourself reinventing the wheel in PHP when you could be using something that is easy peasy at the Apache level.  As far as getting everything up and running - it isn't super hard.  From the link you posted however, it looks like what Dreamhost market as a VPS includes a lot of things you need set up out of the box.  See if they have a demo box!

Answer (score 0):

Dreamhost's standard shared hosting has support for PHP and MySQL and they make it really simple to migrate from that to the VPS you mentioned.
Perhaps it would be worth trying that out beforehand?

Also media temple have scalable, powerful managed hosting.
http://mediatemple.net/